# SQL Server error 493 showing in some SSMS versions

Tags: sql-server, ssms, xquery

I'm getting an `IntelliSense` red squiggly line for following query  in `SSMS` version 17.7 on `Microsoft SQL Server` 2016 (SP2).  After some research it turned out to be error 493 and severity 16. The error in the query is caused by the where clause.

## Query

```
SELECT 
  ClientID,
  Person.query('..') AS Person
FROM ClientInfo CROSS APPLY 
  Info_untyped.nodes('/People/Person') AS People(Person)
 where
 Person.exist(
    '/People/Person[@id=5678]') = 1
```

## Error 493

> The column 'Person' that was returned from the nodes() method cannot be used directly. It can only be used with one of the four XML data type methods, exist(), nodes(), query(), and value(), or in IS NULL and IS NOT NULL checks.

The same query in `SSMS` version 18 and `Microsoft SQL Server` 2016 (SP1) has no issues.

Any idea why ? How to resolve it.

Thank you

```
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION ClientInfoCollection AS 
    '<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns="urn:ClientInfoNamespace" 
    targetNamespace="urn:ClientInfoNamespace" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
      <xsd:element name="People">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Person" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:element name="FirstName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                  <xsd:element name="LastName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                  <xsd:element name="FavoriteBook" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="5" />
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:integer" use="required"/>
              </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>'
    GO
    
    
    CREATE TABLE ClientInfo
    (
      ClientID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
      Info_untyped XML,
      Info_typed XML(ClientInfoCollection)
    );
    INSERT INTO ClientInfo (Info_untyped, Info_typed)
    VALUES
    (
      '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <People>
        <Person id="1234">
          <FirstName>John</FirstName>
          <LastName>Doe</LastName>
        </Person>
        <Person id="5678">
          <FirstName>Jane</FirstName>
          <LastName>Doe</LastName>
        </Person>
      </People>',
      '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <People xmlns="urn:ClientInfoNamespace">
        <Person id="1234">
          <FirstName>John</FirstName>
          <LastName>Doe</LastName>
        </Person>
        <Person id="5678">
          <FirstName>Jane</FirstName>
          <LastName>Doe</LastName>
        </Person>
      </People>'
    )
    
    INSERT INTO ClientInfo (Info_untyped)
    VALUES
    (
      '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <People>
        <Person id="4321">
          <FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
          <LastName>Smith</LastName>
        </Person>
        <Person id="8765">
          <FirstName>Jill</FirstName>
          <LastName>Smith</LastName>
        </Person>
      </People>'
    )
```

Comment: Do you get an error when you execute the query?

Comment: @SalmanA no error upon execution.

Comment: Why not to use the latest stable version? Do you like pain? You could try to find info among fixed bugs after 17.7 version here [Release notes for SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#ssms-1791-latest-ga-release)

Comment: @DenisRubashkin This is only approved version at the company. Did the testing on version 18 on my own.

Comment: But SSMS v17.9.1 is available since 2018-11-21. I don't get the error on v17.8.1

Comment: @DenisRubashkin company is very strict on upgrading.